# If the matrix representation of an orthogonal transformation with respect to a basis is an orthogonal matrix, the basis is an orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I'm learning linear algebra and interested in the relationship between linear transformation, matrix representation and the basis. The followings are my questions:

1. If the matrix representation of an **orthogonal** transformation with respect to a basis is an **orthogonal** matrix, the basis is an orthonormal basis?
2. If the matrix representation of an **symmetric** transformation with respect to a basis is an **symmetric** matrix, the basis is an orthonormal basis?
3. If the matrix representation of an **unitary** transformation with respect to a basis is an **unitary** matrix, the basis is an orthonormal basis?
4. If the matrix representation of an **normal** transformation with respect to a basis is an **normal** matrix, the basis is an orthonormal basis?
5. If the matrix representation of an **Hermite** transformation with respect to a basis is an **Hermite** matrix, the basis is an orthonormal basis?

I know the **converse** of all of them is obvious, and I also hope they are right.

Please prove them or disprove them with counterexample.

Thank you!

Comment: As stated, the answer to all of these is no. Consider the identity transformation. For any basis, this transformation will still be the identity matrix.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Thank you.I misunderstood them. I fixed them in my question.

Comment: @Munchhausen Thx. You let me know they're obviously wrong. I think I am actually a fool.

Comment: @TA123: This is normal exploration. You are not necessarily a fool :-). People hide their unproductive explorations leaving the impression that they never happen. Or they happen with friends at the whiteboard...

Comment: @copper.hat Thx. You're really a kind man. I hope I'll find a friend who has similar math knowledge and interest to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Munchhausen . I know my question is an awful question and my guesses are obviously wrong. But I want my question has an answer, so I write this.

---

Consider **identity transformation**, it is orthogonal, symmetric, unitary, normal and Hermite. For **any basis**, the matrix representation is **identity matrix**, which is orthogonal, symmetric, unitary, normal and Hermite. Therefore, it is a simple and powerful counterexample for all of my questions.